# If I say "car pulled up way too much into the road" what do you understand?

Tags: synonyms, single-word-requests

I am trying to explain someone this situation. There was a car stopped at intersection but its head was sticking out of the cross walk and into other incoming traffic like this picture.
[image]

And I am trying to cross it in front of the car indicated by red arrow. So I was explaining the situation to someone and I said this.

"The car was ***pulled up too much into the road***. If I had to ***go*** in front of the car I would have been on the way of other cars."

Are the words in bold font correct to use in this situation? If not how I could have said this more naturally?

Comment: The car had pulled too far into the road.

Comment: The car had pulled far into the intersection.  "Pulled way too far into the road" sounds like a car coming out of a driveway or parking lot.

Comment: Croc was crossing the street on foot, not car, along the red line.

Comment: Another clear way of putting it was that "the car was blocking the crosswalk"

Comment: He wasn't stopped at the intersection, he was stopped in the intersection. He pulled up into the crosswalk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The car *stopped over the line* or (an example of more detail) *stopped so far over the line that it got in everyone's way* would be sensible in British English. We do use *pull up* to mean *stop* but it doesn't quite fit here (*pull up outside the next house* would be fine as an instruction for someone dropping you off, *pull up short* is fine for stopping too soon).

Other options include simply *...stopped blocking the crossing/crosswalk...* and *... so I couldn't (even) walk in front of it*.

Your suggestion is comprehensible but not natural.

Comment: I think in Britain we would say (speaking as a pedestrian) "The car was blocking the crossing (having overshot the white line)"

Comment: @WS2 that too.  There are plenty of alternatives. It would also be more natural with some intesifying adjectives applied to the car or its driver, or suggesting what the driver might like to do on his own.  But I wouldn't want to offend anyone.

Comment: Is it ok to say "he pulled up past the stop line"?

Comment: @croc yes, though perhaps marginally dated or formal. It's not a good fit to a conversational style but might be heard from someone reporting an accident to the police

Comment: @Chris H what is more common in conversational style?

Comment: @croc what I said in the answer, or what WS2 said in their comment